# killing tunnels for a user connected with ssh -N

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I created a forward only ssh connection with the following:

```
ssh -i id_rsa -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=10  \ 
    -N -n -R 127.0.0.12:8888:127.0.0.12:8888 fwduser@192.168.1.201
```

Mow, on the server, I would like to disconnect that connection. If the user is connected with a shell session then `pkill` works but if it is a forward only connection, then I can't disconnect.

I tried `pkill -u fwd user` and it only works if the user has a connection.
I tried to look in the list of processes and it does not appear

Does anyone know how to disconnect a forward only connection?

Answer (score 2):

It's `ssh` client that's working on your side (local), not sshd. `pgrep -l ssh` should list pids and names. If no clue, try `netstat -tnp|grep -F '127.0.0.1:8888'`. Or run `lsof -itcp@127.0.0.1:8888` and find the pid and kill.

Or `ssh` into the remote machine, and press `~C` and enter on it's own line. You'll get `ssh>` prompt, type -h for help. `~#` lists forwarded connections. Use `-KR127.0.0.1:8888` for killing remote forwarding in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually meant to force disconnection from the server side, not the client side. I have indeed been experimenting with lsof, thanks

Comment: `fuser -kin tcp 8888,,` will prompt to kill process accessing local port 8888. Make sure with `ps -p $(pgrep -d, sshd) -o args,pid`